# How do I minify long statements?

Tags: javascript, minify

I've tried using both [Google Closure](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) and [Yahoo's YUI](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/), but repetitive long lines are not minified.  To fix this I added in :

```
var M = 
{
    m1:  function( html_id, method_call )
    {
        return ( document.getElementById( html_id ).onclick = method_call );
    }
};
```

so that instead of writing

```
document.getElementById(test).onclik = test;
```

I can write

```
M.m1(test,test);
```

However this makes the code difficult to read.  Is there an option I'm missing that will do this for me.  Surely Google or Yahoo know how to do this automatically?

Comment: Just by eyeballing it I could reduce my .js size by 5-20% doing this to long function names.

Comment: I don't understand.  You cannot minimize document or getElementById and onclick -- they are standard JavaScript names and cannot be renamed.  The only thing that appears to be minifiable is "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps closure and YUI are not "optimal enough" at crunching. You could look at the [js1k competitition](http://js1k.com/) entries for some inspiration.

[This post](http://nooshu.com/js1k-javascript-optimisations) gives an overview of some things you can do manually.

[Here's an example of a compressor tool](http://javascriptcompressor.com/) that may do a better job (than closure or YUI for instance) at minimizing.

Comment: Thanks...good info...it seems no minifiers (that I've seen ) can "make the call" of when to add in a function in order to reduce the length of multiple calls to that function...

Comment: Someone should write this up....it would save a solid amount of space...basically the manual section you listed above could easily be made automatic.

Comment: I've never had any of the websites I make cause me issues due to the js files being too big. It's really much more important to have good comments (which as you know bloat the filesize even more). You may be prematurely optimizing.

Comment: What I mean to say is: Minification should always be an *automated* process. You should never develop with a minified version of code, that is just not smart. Manually maintaining two versions of code, one dev version and one hand-minified version, is tremendously impractical.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that long lines aren't minified, it's that 'document' is a host object whose property names are fixed by the JS environment. A minifier works by re-naming your variables with shorter names, but it can't rename the properties of 'document' or other host objects.

If a large part of your code is taken up by these repetitive lines, you should wrap the functionality up in a function that you call in all those places instead of directly using 'document' each time. Some examples of your code would help be more specific about how to do that.

Comment: It does do a replace on document...just not the getElementById() part.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a list of repeated actions you do in your JS
2. Define all those functions, giving them a custom name at the beginning of your script and use those functions wherever you want (take a look [here](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/functions.html))
3. Compress / minify  your javaScript **[here](http://www.minifyjavascript.com/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its unreadable because you created unreadable variable names, why not create relevant variable names and then compile it.

`document.getElementById` cannot be renamed but you can create a function which returns `document.getElementById` which can be renamed.

```
var getElementById = function(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var getElementByIdClick = function(id, method_call){
    return getElementById(id).onclick = method_call;
}
```

This could be compiled to

```
function f(h) {
  return document.getElementById(h);
}
function g(h, k) {
  return f(h).onclick = k;
}
```

Or

```
function f(h){return document.getElementById(h)}function g(h,k){return f(h).onclick=k}
```

The trick to the closure compiler is you use as many variables as possible, not generally a good idea but closure is so good it will decide what's for the best.

So as well as moving reoccurring code into functions you could swap every "dot notation" for a "square bracket notation" and use a variable for every property and method name.

This is an extreme example.

```
var _document=document,getElementById='getElementById', id='test',onclick='onclick',method_call=function(){};
_document[getElementById](id)[onclick] = method_call;
```

Closure compiler will decide whether or not to use the brackets, if it does it will rename your variables.

you could end up with this;

```
var a=document,b='getElementById',c='test',d='onclick',e=function(){};
a[b](c)[d]=e;
```

or it might replace it with the dot notation and remove all variables but at least you have given it the options.

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick=function(){} //method_call
```

`document.getElementById('test')` can never be compiled to this `a[b](c)`

The `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` option for [closure compile](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) will rename functions but it does taking into account how many times the function is used. It might remove the function completely and just use `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: `var u = "undefined";` saves you a few bytes here and there e.g `if(typeof var1==u)`